# Calcular Notas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy trabajando con un sistemas de notas y no logro hacer que me sume las notas al final, y que me diga si esta aprobado o reprobado. La respuesta de la nota final tiene que ser la suma de las 5 notas, mas la prueba y el examen.

[image: vista de la pantalla]

esta es la pantalla de como se veria

```js
 
@section('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @include('includes/mensaje')
        <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Notas</h3>



              <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th class="col-sm-3 " >Nombre</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">Nota 1</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">Nota 2</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">Nota 3</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">Nota 4</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">Nota 5</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">Prueba</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">Examen</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">Nota Final</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">Estado</th>
                            
                            
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                        
                           @foreach($matricula as $notas) 
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$notas->idAlumno}}</td>
                                
                           
                                <td> <input type="text" size="1" id="n1"></td>
                                <td> <input type="text" size="1" id="n2"></td>
                                <td> <input type="text" size="1" id="n3"></td>
                                <td> <input type="text" size="1" id="n4"></td>
                                <td> <input type="text" size="1" id="n5"></td>
                                <td> <input type="text" size="1" id="prueba"></td>
                                <td> <input type="text" size="1" id="examen"></td>
                                <td> <input type="text" size="1" id="notaFinal" disabled></td>
                                <td><span class="label label-success">Aprobado</span></td>
                        
                            </tr>
                           @endforeach
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>



            </div>
            <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                

            </div>
        </div>
```

Este es el codigo del view, he intentado pero no me resulta nada de lo que hago intente con esto 
        a=document.table.n1;
para que se guardar en cada variable lo que contenia el text pero no me resulto

Controlador:

```
class NotasController extends Controller { public function index() 
{ 
     $matricula =Matricula::join('seccion','matricula.idSeccion','=','seccion.idSeccion') 
     ->where('seccion.idDocente','=',auth()->user()->idDocente) 
     ->orderBy('idAlumno') ->get(); 
     return view('admin\notas\index' )->with(["matricula" => $matricula]);
}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar los campos `$matricula` para poder darte una mejor respuesta, por el momento solo puedo comentar que podrias hacer la suma en la misma fila, por ejemplo: `$total = ($notas->n1 + $notas->n2 + $notas->n3 + $notas->n4)`

Comment: class NotasController extends Controller
{
     public function index()
    {
        
        $matricula = Matricula::join('seccion','matricula.idSeccion','=','seccion.idSeccion')
                            
                            ->where('seccion.idDocente','=',auth()->user()->idDocente)
                            ->orderBy('idAlumno')
                            ->get();
                  
        return view('admin\notas\index' )->with(["matricula" => $matricula]);;
    }

Comment: ¿No termina de quedar claro, deseas mandar desde el controlador el estado de aprobado o reprobado o deseas hacerlo en la vista?, ya que de ser esto último entonces lo lograrías con JS

Comment: lo deseo mandar desde la vista